# When adding fields to my database i get blank data

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

im trying to add data to my database but this code seems to just add blank data. Any solutions would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbh.php';

$start = $_POST['starttime'];
$finish = $_POST['finishtime'];
$dat = $_POST['date'];
$id = $_POST['userid'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO shift (shiftStart, shiftFinish, shiftDate) 
VALUES ('$start', '$finish', '$dat')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result->affected_rows){
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
echo'<pre>',print_r($row),'</pre>';
}else{
echo"didnt work";
}


//header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: print your sql query like `echo $sql` and check what it returns?

Comment: I will try this, however the code works when i GET instead of POST the data from the form?... this is what i get when i echo                       "connected INSERT INTO shift (shiftStart, shiftFinish, shiftDate) VALUES ('', '', '')didnt work"

Comment: `For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.` So why do you expect to be able to fetch a row from `$result` after an INSERT query?

Comment: Ignore the query below that was me experimenting with other results before this.

Comment: ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***

Comment: Maybe a silly question but, does your form (html) has type="POST"?

Comment: Following @Marvinoo_'s comment, you should check that your parameters are set.

Comment: **The mysqli_affected_rows() function returns the number of affected rows in the previous SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE, or DELETE query.**

Comment: *however the code works when i GET instead of POST the data from the form?*  if its working when u have used $_GET that means ur form method is get if u wanna use post change method to post

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO shift (shiftStart, shiftFinish, shiftDate) 
VALUES (".$start.", ".$finish.", ".$dat.")";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Try the above if any are string values you will need to add quotation marks around them single one `('".$start."')`.

Comment: Tried this and it doesnt add anything this way, CORRECTION... when i use ('".$start."') it still inserts blank data

Comment: that sounds like its not got a value. Is the value a string?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use var_dump() to check all $_POST variables - do they have values?
If the method of your form is "get" you should use $_GET.

Step 2. After finding the (probably missing) variables please change you SQL query, otherwise you will have big risk of injection.
You should use prepared statements everywhere dealing with database. Check manual - http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php .
And, by the way, you missing execute () function in your code.

Comment: *And, by the way, you missing execute () function in your code.* what is he going to execute?

Comment: How it should be:
`code
/* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (?)"))) {
     echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

/* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */
$id = 1;
if (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $id)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}`